MetaTrader 5 and Python problems with RSI and Alligator chart integration
How can I implement RSI and Alligator on the same chart?
I am developing a robot in Python to automate trading operations.
I saw that RSI works in a range from 0 to 100 while Alligator works around the maximum and minimum value of the candles.
However, I saw that in MetaTrader 5 on the cell phone it is possible to integrate the 2 indicators on the same chart.
Do you know what is the logic to follow in this case?
I tried to normalize the Alligator values in a range from 0 to 100 but it is very inaccurate, what would be the correct way to do it?
def normalize_series(series, target_min=0, target_max=100):
    min_val = series.min()
    max_val = series.max()
    normalized = (series - min_val) / (max_val - min_val) * (target_max - target_min) + target_min
    return normalized

